# .htaccess redirect woes — not completing

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So, at the moment, my .htaccess looks a little like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^colorspace\.am$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.colorspace\.am$
RewriteRule ^portfolio\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/i\.colorspace\.am\/portfolio$1" [R=301,L]
```

I want to move all the content from my root directory into a subdomain (which I've done) but I don't want the links people have to not work. www.colorspace.am/portfolio needs to redirect to i.colorspace.am/portfolio, and all the sets contained therein (ie /portfolio/YYYYMMDD) also need to be 'adjusted' on the fly (www.colorspace.am/portfolio/YYYYMMDD -> i.colorspace.am/porfolio/YYYYMMDD

NOTE: i.colorspace.am contain's 2011's content; ii.colorspace.am will contain 2012. They're two entirely different WP installs with their own respective databases. Not sure if it's relevant but..

What seems to be happening is that /portfolio is instructed to redirect to i.colorspace.am/portfolio, but for whatever reason it's ending up at i.colorspace.am

IF there's a way I can make any www.colorspace.am/folder/sub-folder redirect to i.colorspace.am/folder/sub-folder (wildcard?) ..that would be amazing. But I'd be just as happy with a single fully working redirect at this point.

NOTE: the redirect code was generated by my administration panel. I tried

```
Redirect /portfolio http://i.colorspace.am/portfolio
```

But it resulted in a 'too many redirects' error.

Answer (score 0):

After the redirection from

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio\/?(.*)$ http//i.colorspace.am/portfolio$1 [R=301,L]
```

The rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Is accessed again. That is the reason it's ending up at `i.colorspace.am`.

Add these 2 rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?i.colorspace\.am$
RewriteRule protfolio -[L]
```

in order mentioned below.

also change (just a small optimization)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^colorspace\.am$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.colorspace\.am$
RewriteRule ^portfolio\/?(.*)$ http//i.colorspace.am/portfolio$1 [R=301,L]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?colorspace\.am$ 
RewriteRule ^portfolio\/?(.*)$ http//i.colorspace.am/portfolio$1 [R=301,L]
```

and put it inside of `IfModule` block in the same order mentioned below.

Have just the below in your `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#add these 2 lines:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?i.colorspace\.am$
RewriteRule protfolio -[L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?colorspace\.am$ 
RewriteRule ^portfolio\/?(.*)$ http//i.colorspace.am/portfolio$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Was the last block (beginning # BEGIN WordPress, ending </IfModule>) the *FULL* .htaccess code, or just what's contained within the WP/IfModule? I ask because there were bits where you said 'add below' etc etc, and then your final code contains rules that I was putting outside of the module ..inside of it. So should I be having the rules outside of the module and the same ones therein or am I just making a huge mess of things :|

I tried [only] the code above, and I end back up at i.colorspace.am ..so I'm going to copy them back to the outside and see how that goes :|

Comment: Just tried it with the code inside and out. No luck :( BUT, it does seem to be catching everything (previously /portfolio would redirect but /portfolio/YYYYMMDD would not)

Comment: @AlexMasters Just have the rewriterules specified in the answer. Also, delete your browser cache. 301(permanent) redirects are cached rigorously.

Comment: Just confirming: the last block of code is the /entire/ code that I'm using, correct?

Comment: @AlexMasters Yup. from `# BEGIN WordPress` to `# END WordPress`. _Remember to delete your browser cache_.

Comment: Used the code stated. No dice. Tried on Chrome, IE and my BB browser w/ cleared cache :(

Comment: Until it's resolved, I've just made each of the directories and put a index.php file containing <?
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.new-url.com" ); 
?> in them. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: @AlexMasters My bad! `RewriteRule /protfolio -[L]` has to be `RewriteRule protfolio -[L]`. See updated answer.

Comment: Discovered the issue. I had .htaccess in /, /i and /ii. Once I stripped the WP code from the root, the redirections worked.